# Created new user and can't select database

Tags: php, mysql

Problem - Created new user with 'minimal' permissions and when I plug in the account info I get the error 'No Database Selected'

In MySQL Workbench I can connect to the database and select data. But not through PHP.

Permissions - `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES`

```
 $db_select = mysql_select_db('DBNAME',$conn);

    if($db_select){ 

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 LIMIT 1";

          if ($result = mysql_query($sql)) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);         
          }
           else print mysql_error();

    }
```

UPDATE: When I run query with PDO it works.

Comment: You should use **[`MySQLi`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[`PDO`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** instead of **[`mysql_*`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)** functions, which are deprecated and will be removed in the future versions of PHP. [More information avalible here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Have you granted your user rights to that database?  In addition to granting a user permissions to do certain things, you have to grant them permission to do those things in a particular database.

Comment: remember that accounts are specific to the connection's source. e.g. `grant ... to user@localhost` is of no use if you're connecting via TCP and mysql sees you coming in as `user@some.other.ip.address`. The exception to this is wildcarding, which generally should not be used.

Comment: I am using the actual dbname, DBNAME is just a placeholder for public eyes.

Comment: I have schema privileges of HOST `%` SCHEMA `DBNAME` PRIVILEGES `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES`

Comment: I have also flushed privileges since creating the new user.